# Connecting to Kafka using SSLStream

Tags: c#, ssl, apache-kafka

I am trying to connect to Kafka using SSLStream.
The C# code that I am trying is:

```
 using (var client = tcpClientBuilder.CreateTcpClient())
 {
     if(!client.Connected)
          client.Connect("xx.x.xxx.xx", 9093);
     using (var stream = client.GetStream())
    {
      using (var ssl = new SslStream(stream, false, ValidateCertificate))
      {                 
         ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("xx.x.xxx.xx", _certificateCollection, 
                                SslProtocols.Tls, false);
  }
```

The certificate file I use is a PEM file, and the C# library I am using is https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net

The exception I get back in the validateCrtificate call back is:

Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

The kafka server is running fine, and able to connect to it with Java. I cannot find anything wrong in the log files (attached). The code for ValidateCertificate is:

```
 private bool ValidateCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            if (sslPolicyErrors.ToString() != "None")
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I also have a SSLSream handshake method called before sending any message to kafka.  This executes without any errors.

```
private void HandShake(X509Certificate2Collection certificateCollection, IPHostEntry entry, SslStream sslStream)
        {
            try
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(entry.HostName, certificateCollection, SslProtocols.Default, false);
                sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(handshake), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("handshake").Length);
                sslStream.Flush();
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException ae)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

If anyone can throw any light on this, it would be very helpful..
The certificate file I use is a PEM file, and the C# library I am using is https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net. The certificate files have been exported to Kafka Correctly.

The error I get back is

> "Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond."

The kafka server is running, and I cannot find anything wrong in the log files.

Note: I amm able to connect to Kafka using the JRoland SDK([https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net][1])

Kafka Version: Kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0
If anyone can throw any light on this, it would be very helpful..

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think that library is maintained. I'd suggest using the Confluent one

Comment: That is ideally desired, but, I have many existing clients that use JRoland SDK, and for them switching to Confluent is not an option.